# Поправить меню на jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте. 
Нужно, чтобы при клике .menu1 приписывался, скажем, "deactive" к ".menu3".

```
 $(".menu1").click(function(){
 $(".menu2").toggleClass("active");
 });
```

Comment: `deactive` - это класс?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По поводу `deactive` не знаю, а вот по поводу `active` - знаю. Может быть Вы имели в виду это:

```
 $('.menu1').click(function() {
        $(".menu3").removeClass("active");
        $(".menu2").toggleClass("active");
    });
```

Comment: Мой код работает. Но нужно дописать "когда к .menu2 добавляется active, то к .menu3 добавляется deactive "

Таким образом, в меню при открытии одной вкладки закрывался второй.

Comment: @Lion, прошу прощения, а что такое `deactive`? Почему бы Вам не убрать у него `active` вот так: `$('.menu3').removeClass('active');`

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогли!